# How can i click on component behind any component in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let say i have a two surface in a box and they are on top of each other;

```
Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp).clickable{},
                        color =  Color.Red
                    ) {}
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp),
                        color = Color.Blue
                    ){}
                }
```

View:

[image]

When I click on the blue surface, I want the red surface to be clicked.

Or I want to make the blue surface "Click Invisible"

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want both red and blue Composables to trigger actions or both to have ripple when you click blue one?

Comment: i want to trigger actions and ripple efect only for red one. i can think  workaround with your answer but I missed a detail that i am using combinedClickable for longPress so cant use interactionSource.

Comment: There is a overload  function of `Modifier.combinedClickable()` that takes `MutableInteractionSource` and  `Indication` as parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you want red one to have ripple effect when you touch blue Composable you can use a shared `InteractionSource` to trigger interaction for different composables

```
//  This interaction source is set by inner composable to trigger ripple on outer one
val interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp)
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = rememberRipple(),
                onClick = {

                }

            ),
        color = Color.Red
    ) {}
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .clickable {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    val press = PressInteraction.Press(Offset.Zero)
                    interactionSource.emit(
                        press
                    )
                    interactionSource.emit(
                        PressInteraction.Release(press)
                    )
                }
            },
        color = Color.Blue
    ) {}
}
```

The issue you will get here with blue Composable's ripple is it will start from Offset.Zero. You can set center of blue Composable manually. I don't know if there is a way to get exact position of press from InteractionSource or Interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same like this -

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp).clickable {},
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            color =  Color.Red
        ) {}
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp) ,
            color = Color.Blue
        ){}
    }
```

You can centre it inside another box if you want.